# Click on title to scrape data using selenium and scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver


url='https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput='
driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
detail=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tbody//td[6]")))
detail.click()
```

Error will be in these:

```
detail=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tbody//td[6]")))
    detail.click()
```

I want that they click on the title of  these is page [link](https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput=)
[image]

and then there will scrape these information. How to scrape these data.
[image]

Comment: Your code is so far from what you want to do that I don't even know from where to start:) How and why do you want to use Scrapy here? What is your current problem? Any errors/wrong output? Do you want to scrape data for each entry or only from specific?

Comment: Scrape each  entry and  the error wil be occur on these line `detail=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td//img//@src"))).click()`

Comment: I want ue scrapy because the data is almost 4000+ and scrapy will scrape data fast as compare to selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot locate *HTML attribute* to click on it. Try to replace

```
detail=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td//img//@src"))).click()
```

with

```
detail = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='info']")))
detail.click()
```

**UPDATE**
Since your ScrapySelenium approach doeasn't seem to work, try common Selenium approach. Then you could adapt it to Scrapy

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.aeafa.es/asociados.php?provinput='
driver.get(url)

for mail in driver.find_elements("xpath", "//p/a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]"):
    print(mail.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Note that you don't need to open each details popup to get required email text

Comment: NameError: name 'wait' is not defined provide these error

Comment: @AmenAziz you said that error was on `click` line. So how `wait = WebDriverWait(url, 30)` worked before?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: @AmenAziz did your ScrapySelenium approach worked before? Have you already use it in this way?

Comment: No I will tied this first time

Comment: if you any other  feasible solution share with me

Comment: after extract inforamtion chrome are not close?

Comment: add `driver.quit()`

Comment: With out click how can extract the data?

Comment: can you little bit explain it

Comment: You don't need to click details button and open popup since all the data is already in page source (though it's not displayed)

Comment: So I can use scrapy also ?

Comment: I would simply use [python-requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) + [lxml](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)

Comment: Can you please make the xpath for `Telefono`and `poblacion`

Comment: Try `"//p/a[starts-with(@href, 'tel:')]"` and `"//p[contains(text(), 'Población:')]/strong"`

Comment: I want remove dot from phone number

Comment: `get_attribute('textContent').replace('.', '')`